# Treating `[` as a literal when replacing in a string within SAS proc SQL using the translate function

Tags: sas

I am using SAS version 9.4_M5. I have a data file in SAS with a column of values with format of `08.42.18 hrs __[0001122].gif`.
I am wanting to replace the `[` with `[[]`. So the value of `08.42.18 hrs __[0001122].gif` would be changed to `08.42.18 hrs __[[]0001122].gif`.

Below is an SQL test (note: I'm simply using `sashelp.class` as an example table since I am hard-coding the values into the SQL for this example so anyone with SAS can run it).

```
%_eg_conditional_dropds(testcase);
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE testcase AS 
   SELECT 
   (translate('08.42.18 hrs __[0001122].gif','ffd','gif')) as t1,
   (translate('08.42.18 hrs __[0001122].gif','[[]','[')) as t2,
   (translate('08.42.18 hrs __[0001122].gif',']]',']')) as t3,
   (translate('08.42.18 hrs __[0001122].gif','blah','[[]')) as t4,
   (translate('08.42.18 hrs __[0001122].gif','him','\\[')) as t5,
   (translate('08.42.18 hrs __[0001122].gif','him','\[')) as t6
   FROM sashelp.class
 QUIT;

/* value of t1 changed to `08.42.18 hrs __[0001122].ffd` */
/* value of t2 stays the same `08.42.18 hrs __[0001122].gif` */
/* value of t3 stays the same `08.42.18 hrs __[0001122].gif` */
/* value of t4 gets weird and changes to `08.42.18 hrs __l0001122a.gif` */
/* value of t5 changes `[` to `m` */
/* value of t6 changes `[` to `i` */
```

It seems the translate function is treating the brackets as regex somehow but I was not able to find anything in the docs about it and the behavior is odd. I have not figured out how to force the translate function to treat the `[` as a literal. Any ideas? - thank you

Comment: Translate does character replacement, try TRANWRD instead.

Comment: Your first translate() call is saying to change both of the letters `g` and `i` to `f` and also change the letter `f` to `d`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `tranwrd` instead.

```
data test;
    string = tranwrd('08.42.18 hrs __[0001122].gif', '[', '[[]');
run;
```

`08.42.18 hrs __[[]0001122].gif`

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

Syntax

```
TRANSLATE(expression, to-characters, from-characters)
```

Details

*Values of to-characters and from-characters correspond on a character-by-character basis; TRANSLATE changes the first character in from-characters to the first character in to-characters,and so on. If to-characters has fewer characters than from-characters, TRANSLATE changes the extra from-characters characters to blanks. If to-characters has more characters than from-characters, TRANSLATE ignores the extra to-characters.*